# Rspec content vs text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I've run across a couple examples where people test for the content of an html element with `page.should have_selector "title", content: "my awsome content"`, but this seems to always pass.  The correct call seems to be `page.should have_selector "title", text: "my awsome content"` (notice `text:` instead of `content:`).

What is the `content:` selector for in this Rspec call?

Comment: Wrong? Although it may depend on which back end you're using. AFAIK Capybara and Webrat use `:text` and would ignore `:content`, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

`have_selector` doesn't support a `:content` option.

Long answer:

Rspec creates dynamic methods that translates calls like `[].should be_empty` to `[].empty?.should == true` and, in your case, `page.should have_selector "title", content: "my awesome content"` to `page.has_selector?("title, content: "my awesome content").should == true`.

Capybara provides the [has_selector?](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L34-L38) method, which basically just passes its parameters to its `test/unit` style assertion, [assert_selector](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L83-L89):

```
def has_selector?(*args)
  assert_selector(*args)
rescue Capybara::ExpectationNotMet
  return false
end
```

`assert_selector` then passes its parameters again to the Capybara finder method, `all()`, returning `true` if it found any matches and raising an exception if it doesn't (which `has_selector?` catches and then returns `false` with).

```
def assert_selector(*args)
  synchronize do
    result = all(*args)
    result.matches_count? or raise Capybara::ExpectationNotMet, result.failure_message
  end
  return true
end
```

The `all` method returns all of the results that match the query. [This](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb#L102-119) is where we'll find the documentation on acceptable options:

```
# @overload all([kind], locator, options)
#   @param [:css, :xpath] kind                 The type of selector
#   @param [String] locator                    The selector
#   @option options [String, Regexp] text      Only find elements which contain this text or match this regexp
#   @option options [Boolean] visible          Only find elements that are visible on the page. Setting this to false
#                                              (the default, unless Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true), finds
#                                              invisible _and_ visible elements.
# @return [Array[Capybara::Element]]           The found elements
```

We can see that `content` is not listed as a valid options, so is just ignored.

Comment: With the caveat that comments are ultimately meaningless; it's the code that needs to be checked to be certain.